# как передать атрибуты по кнопке в форму, с нескольких кнопок

Tags: javascript

как передать атрибуты по кнопке в форму, с нескольких кнопок.
заходит только одна кнопка!

всем заранее благодарен!!!!

```html
<div id="order_cancel" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
            
            <form id="form_contact" method="POST" action="" novalidate="novalidate">
                <input type="hidden" name="Id" class="hiddenValue" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.data_btn').click(function(){
       var data_title  = $('.data_btn').attr('data_title')
       $('.hiddenValue').val(data_title);

       var data_head  = $('.data_btn').attr('data_head')
       $('.modal-title').text(data_head);
       })
})
</script>

<div class="fl">
   <a href="#order_cancel" class="data_btn btn btn_big_violet" 
             data_head="Заголовок в форму111" 
             data_title="название 111"
   >Кнопка</a>
</div>

<div class="fl">
   <a href="#order_cancel" class="data_btn btn btn_big_violet" 
             data_head="Заголовок в форму222" 
             data_title="название 222"
   >Кнопка</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Не вижу атрибута `data_name` кроме как в Вашем JS.

Comment: Замените `$('.data_btn').attr('data_title')` и `$('.data_btn').attr('data_name')` на `$(this).attr('data_title')` и `$(this).attr('data_name')` соответственно.

Comment: @Simon спасибо поправил код в stackoverflow, запутался. видимо data_name зарезервировано где-то, поменял на др название заработало. но только с 1 кнопкой (на 1 странице их 2шт).  подскажите пжл как мне в JS их все отловить. на PHP я с названиями разберусь типа data_btn_1, data_btn_2, data_btn_3 и тд

Comment: Ну я же вроде отписал уже как

Comment: @Simon спасибо огромное!!! еще бы решение написали и я отметил вас, а то как-то сам себе. А вы помогли мне!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете просто поменять `$('.data_btn').attr('data_title')` и `$('.data_btn').attr('data_name')` на `$(this).attr('data_title')` и `$(this).attr('data_name')` соответственно. Где `$(this)` это текущий jQuery элемент на который нажал пользователь, то есть одна из Ваших кнопок.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.data_btn').click(function() {
    $('.hiddenValue').val($(this).attr('data_title'));
    $('.modal-title').text($(this).attr('data_head'));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="order_cancel" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>

      <form id="form_contact" method="POST" action="" novalidate="novalidate">
        <input type="hidden" name="Id" class="hiddenValue" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="fl">
  <a href="#order_cancel" class="data_btn btn btn_big_violet" data_head="Заголовок в форму111" data_title="название 111">Кнопка</a>
</div>

<div class="fl">
  <a href="#order_cancel" class="data_btn btn btn_big_violet" data_head="Заголовок в форму222" data_title="название 222">Кнопка</a>
</div>
```

Comment: еще раз спасибки!

Comment: И вообще, в `html` есть `data` атрибуты которые пшутся через дефис, и можно получать значение через `.dataset`, зачем творить через `attr`?

Comment: @OliverPatterson это вопрос ко мне или?

Comment: Думаю можно совместить)

Comment: @OliverPatterson ну так-то я в принципе никогда до этого не встречал чтобы кто-то делал это через нижнее подчеркивание, просто минимально изменил исходный код который был у пользователя. Так-то естественно обычно это через дефис, где затем можно использовать  `dataset`, как Вы упомянули, ну а в jQuery можно через `data()`, что тоже удобнее чем `attr()`. Могу отредактировать ответ с альтернативными вариантами)